# How to get the current console command in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I can see if a script is running in the console with the `App::runningInConsole()` command, but I would like to know (for audit logging purposes) which command has been run from console.

To add some context - I need to log whenever a system or user accesses a certain type of data. For users, that's pretty simple - I can use `Auth::user()` and get their IP address from `Request`, but for console commands, it's a little more difficult.

I can figure out if a console command is running, which is good, but I need to be able to record *which* console command is running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not see a way to get that information directly Laravel. I'm also not sure how that would be possible, as you can have one command executing other commands or even creating a new application instance like some test tools do.

There is however a way to achieve that using plain PHP. You can check the server/environment variables to identify how application was executed.

Have a look at

```
dd($_SERVER['argv']);
```

If you run a command this should give you the command name in **$_SERVER['argv'][1]**

You can find more information here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping there was just some poorly documented laravel feature that you could call (like `App::currentCommand()` or something). In the instance of a command calling a command, I would prefer to log the inner command.

Comment: When laravel executes a command it updates the name of the process that it is running in. If you set $processTitle for your command you should get back whatever you put there by calling "cli_get_process_title()", just make sure you are in CLI mode.

Comment: If you set "protected $processTitle = _ _ CLASS _ _;" you will get what you need, but I would call it a hack, not a feature.

Answer (score 6):

To get console command together with arguments you should use something like that:

```
$command = \Request::server('argv', null);
if (is_array($command)) {
   $command = implode(' ', $command);
}
```

In Laravel you can use `\Request:server` to get `$_SERVER` variables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `$SERVER['arg']` is that it doesnt work when you execute the command on the GUI.

I fixed the problem adding the next code on the command.

```
private function getAttributes() 
{
    $arguments = $this->arguments();
    unset($arguments[0]);
    $arguments = collect($arguments)->implode(' ');
    $options = collect($this->options())->filter(function($item) {
        return $item;
    })->map(function($item, $key) {
        $return = '--'.$key;
        if($item!==true) {
            $return .= '='.$item;
        }
        return $return;
    })->implode(' ');
    return $arguments.' '.$options;
}
```

and you get it calling `$this->getAttributes()` and you will get all the command with the attributes