# Laravel: detect if running migrations

Tags: laravel, migration

I have setup some event listeners in which I would like to detect if I'm runnnig database migrations or a normal request/command.

Is there some way of knowing this? Global flag? Environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see anything built-in. You could probably PHP's `debug_backtrace` to detect that a migration file is currently in use.

Answer (score 5):

You can check if the console is being used with `App::runningInConsole()` ... that might be sufficient depending on how you are running the migrations.

**Update:**

OK, after doing some more digging, it looks like you can hack your way to the info you need using the follow example:

```
if(app()->runningInConsole()) {
    // we are running in the console
    $argv = \Request::server('argv', null);

    // :$ php artisan migrate:refresh -v
    //
    // gives:
    //
    // $argv = array (
    //      0 => 'artisan',
    //      1 => 'migrate:refresh',
    //      2 => '-v',
    // )  

    if($argv[0] == 'artisan' && \Illuminate\Support\Str::contains($argv[1],'migrate')) {
        // we are running the artisan migrate command
    }
}
```

Source: [How to get the current console command in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994132/how-to-get-the-current-console-command-in-laravel)

Comment: I'd note that if you use Artisan commands for anything else - including Laravel's built-in cron - this would apply there too.

Comment: @Peter not really sufficient... I don't want it to trigger at every artisan command... Just the `migrate` ones. Is there a way to get the currently running command?

Comment: I've added an update that might get your the info you need in an ugly but functional way.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Laravel fires several events while running migrations:

`Illuminate\Database\Events\MigrationsStarted` : A batch of migrations is about to be executed.

`Illuminate\Database\Events\MigrationsEnded` : A batch of migrations has finished executing.

`Illuminate\Database\Events\MigrationStarted` : A single migration is about to be executed.

`Illuminate\Database\Events\MigrationEnded` : A single migration has finished executing.

You can utilize this to do anything you want. For example:

```php
// change default Log channel when running migrations
Event::listen(function (MigrationsStarted $event) {
    config()->set('logging.default', 'migration');
});
```

In your case, you can set a key in your app config files like `app.running_migrations` and set it to `true` in the event listener.